# Change a Image in ribbon button_click event for outlook ribbon button control using c#?

Tags: c#, xml, callback, outlook-addin

i done to create a custom tab and ribbon button in outlook addin using Ribbon(XML) in C#.

i want to change the ribbon button image when i click the button.how to  i acheive that?

here my XML Design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load" loadImage="GetCustomImage">

  <ribbon>

    <tabs>

      <tab id="TabAddIns" label="Mail Security">


        <group id="Group2" >

          <button id="Encrypt" onAction="Encrypt_Click" label="Encrypt" size="large" image="email-security.png" getVisible="Control_Visible" />


        </group>

      </tab>

    </tabs>

  </ribbon>

</customUI>
```

GetCustomImage Function:

```
public stdole.IPictureDisp GetCustomImage(string imageName)
        {

                return PictureConverter.ImageToPictureDisp(Properties.Resources.email_security);


        }
```

Actually i want to change the "Encrypt" Button image(email-security.png) into another one when after click that button.i have already try to call the GetCustomImage() in Encrypt button click.but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying getImage callback on the button XML element.

Comment: thanks for your reply Dmirty.How to call the getimage callback in XML?

Comment: You don't call it, Outlook does. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx